Why might an ozone UV spa pool cause test strips to fail for chlorine?
My spa pool chemistry guide claims that the test strips are not accurate for measuring chlorine in a spa pool with UV and ozone. Why might that be the case? My spa pool company also sells me the chemicals, so they're incentivised to get me to over do chemicals.
The test strips are branded spasupplies and test for total hardness, free chlorine, total chlorine, total alkalinity, and pH.

UV and ozone may alter composition of active components of the strips, so they give altered color intensity as reaction with active chlorine.

Take a sample inside where there is no uv and ozone?

Ozone and chlorine disinfect in a radically different way and their tests are different.

Add more details about the unnamed test strips.

@Poutnik can you elaborate on the chemical processes underlying your claim? The spa company claims something similar but does not elaborate.

It may largely depends on the nature of the test strips, but these usually test chlorine content by non-specific reactions with strong oxidants, what involves also ozone. Ozone is formed also by UV interaction with water. Degradation of stripe reagents by ozone as very strong oxidant would be rather secondary. // I am curious why you want to measure free chlorine in a pool treated by ozone or UV?

The guidance manual recommends a shock dose of chlorine every two weeks and a small dose after every use. It seems like a lot. People in my area complain about clothing getting ruined by spa pools, which suggests to me that people typically overchlorinate their spa pools. I would like to be able to test my chlorine levels to ensure they don't get too high

Does anyone know of any chlorination guides for pools with ozone and UV sanitation, not by chemical supply companies?

Have you calculated the expected concentration of chlorine (typical number IIRC 10 mg/L) from the amount of active chlorine provided by the substances and the volume of the pool? It should not deviate much from measured values if water is of good quality. (If water should be replaced months ago, chlorine content may be minimal, spent on organics and concentration of dissolved organic compounds is comparable to input of waste water cleaning plant - I measured it once personally.)

I don't know anything about the decay rate of chlorine, so can't calculate this. What's the decay rate of chlorine?

I meant the applied dose, not decay rate. Chlorine does not decay, but partly escaped to air, partly reacts with organic compounds ( like from sweat), microorganisms or algae . It is experimental value that cannot be calculated. It can be estimated from published experience.
